# supply values to onSubmit() function of a webpage using c#

Tags: c#, html

My task: In a website(my university website) when results are generated using my c#(windows or web application) code automatically the roll number's will be incremented and results will be stored in my database.i need to supply values for a textbox in the university website from my code.,im able to find the html input tag name(regno) for the textbox.,the problem is,the HTML page is using onSubmit event with return values(to validate the roll no entered in the textbox) and it is redirected to another page(the output results page).How to do i supply values to the onSubmit method (from my C# code)such that it returns "true"and i should be able to retireve the values from the output page also.pls help,i dont know where to start,or how to start.

```
  <SCRIPT language=JavaScript>
    <!--
      function checkregno()
         {
          if (window.RegExp)
          {
            strval=document.forms["result"]["regno"].value;
            reExp=new RegExp("^\\d{14}$");
          }
       function dele()
          {
            document.result.action="http://www.annauniv.edu";
            document.result.submit();  
          }
         //-->
       </SCRIPT>
      <META content="MSHTML 6.00.2800.1491" name=GENERATOR></HEAD>
      <BODY text=#000000 bgColor=gray 
      onload="javascript:document.forms['result']['regno'].focus()">
      <FORM name=result onSubmit="return checkregno();" action=/cgi-bin/result/resgrbarchpg.pl method=post>
      <INPUT maxLength=14 size=14 name=regno>
       <INPUT onClick="return checkregno();" type=submit value=Submit> 
     <INPUT type=reset value=Clear name=clear>
```

the code i use to retrieve the page source is:
             static string GetHtmlPage(string strURL)
             {

```
         String strResult;
         WebResponse objResponse;
         WebRequest objRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(strURL);
         objResponse = objRequest.GetResponse();
         using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(objResponse.GetResponseStream()))
         {
         strResult = sr.ReadToEnd();
         sr.Close();
         }
         return strResult;
          }
          protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
          string tablecode = null;
          String TheUrl = "http://www.annauniv.edu/1234566789/grbarchpg.html? regno=23010205001";
          string response = GetHtmlPage(TheUrl);
           tablecode = response;

         HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
       doc.LoadHtml(@tablecode);

        TextBox1.Text = tablecode;
```

}

Comment: Have you tried anything ?? Try something and then if it dont work post what you did and what is'nt working and how it is not working THEN will be glad to help. We are not here to do your homework for yourself.

Comment: As a start get fiddler and use the request and see what goes out and then learn HTTPWEBREQUEST (post,get) for how to replicate those calls. There are tons of examples on the net so you wont have any problem.

Comment: @confusedMind your reply was awesome., it helped me find the solution,they used the request headers to send the values.,thanks a lot..i never knew about fiddler,once again thank you :)

Comment: @user2605748 i entered that as an answer you should mark it if it helped you :).

Answer (score 1):

As a start get fiddler and use the request and see what goes out and then learn HTTPWEBREQUEST (post,get) for how to replicate those calls. There are tons of examples on the net so you wont have any problem.